# Handling Alarm notification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I start to combine alarm manager and notification manager on android, and this is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setReminderAlarm();
}

public void setReminderAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.NOTIF_ID, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000L, pendingIntent);
}
```

**ReminderReceiver.java**

```
public static int NOTIF_ID = 101;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    showAlarmNotification(context);
}

public void showAlarmNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intentClick = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentClick, 0);
    NotificationManager notificationManagerCompat = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cinema)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(pendingClick)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIF_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Every time I run the application, the notification always appears even though I have set the time. How do I prevent that? 
Thank you.

Comment: So you want alarm will be triggered 7:59 everyday.

Comment: yes i want my alarm triggered 6:59 every day

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are setting the time to current day. So if you are opening your app after 6:00, your alarm manager will immediately fire.

You need to check whether the time is over 6:00 for the current day, if yes you need to change the date to the next day:

```
public void setReminderAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.NOTIF_ID, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    // Checking whether current hour is over 6
    if (curHr >= 6)
    {
        // Since current hour is over 6, setting the date to the next day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000L, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: so how your way work, why we need to add int curHr and date there??

Comment: Because you are setting the time to current day. So if you are opening your app after 6:00, your alarm manager will immediately fire. So you need to check whether the time is over 6:00 for the current day, if yes you need to change the date to the next day. So alarm trigger on next day on 06:00.